# When I try to run my JMeter recorded script, showing below error

Tags: jmeter

> ERROR o.a.j.g.a.ActionRouter: Error processing
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start@37ebc9d8
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:193)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:174)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.startEngine(Start.java:164)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Start.doAction(Start.java:108)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_131]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_131]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]

Comment: The exception suggests that JMeter has nothing to run, no elements whatsoever, no even Thread Group. But you need to post your script and screenshot to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In apache Jmeter- I have recorded the script/Testcase of [Https] sites. When I try to run it's displayed the above error, 
1. Searched other sites about the error they suggested due to missing/conflict library file problem. so deleted the Jmeter software and downloaded newly
2. Ran the script it's working fine